# Multiple server blocks in nginx: Php not working on server 2

Tags: linux, nginx, php, php-fpm

I have a nginx server running on my webserver.
I would like to achieve the following:

- example.com + www.example.com -> /my/web/dir/www
- pma.example.com -> /my/web/dir/pma

The first point is not problem an everything works fine.
For the second point I edited /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default and copied the existing server block to create a new one for pma.example.com.

```
server {
    listen   80;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }   

    location ~ (?U)\.php(/.*$|$) {
        gzip off;

        #^((?U).*/echo)(/?.+)$;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/.+)?$;

        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        #try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        if (!-e $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return 404;
        }

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
}

server {
    listen   80;

    root /usr/share/nginx/pma;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name pma.example.com;

    location ^~ /{
        auth_basic              "Restricted Area";
        auth_basic_user_file    conf/pma_htpasswd;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

        gzip off;

        #^((?U).*/echo)(/?.+)$;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.php)(/.+)?$;

        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        #try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        if (!-e $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return 404;
        }

        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
}
```

The first one still works fine and PHP is working fine too.
The second one does not work.

I created a index.php file in the pma directory to test the settings:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Unfortunately if I enter pma.example.com in my browser (latest Chrome) it just wants to download the file.
I'm not very experienced with webservers so I would like to ask you for help.
How can I get this to work that I can use PHP on the second server block? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem by following this tutorial on digitalocean.com:
[How To Configure Single and Multiple WordPress Site Settings with Nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-single-and-multiple-wordpress-site-settings-with-nginx)

I left out the Wordpress specific parts and now it works just fine.